MariaDB Server not getting started
Can some one help resolving this issue
DBI connect('host=127.0.0.1;database=','bugs',...) failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (115) at /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/DBI.pm line 689,  line 960.
DBI::ANON(undef, undef) called at /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/DBI.pm line 746
DBI::connect("DBI", "dbi:MariaDB:host=127.0.0.1;database=", "bugs", "Test1234", HASH(0x5578447c9948)) called at lib/DBIx/Connector.pm line 31
DBIx::Connector::_connect(DBIx::Connector=HASH(0x557844a4e208)) called at lib/DBIx/Connector.pm line 75
DBIx::Connector::dbh(DBIx::Connector=HASH(0x557844a4e208)) called at (eval 610) line 17
Bugzilla::DB::dbh(Bugzilla::DB::MariaDB=HASH(0x557844b5a260)) called at Bugzilla/DB.pm line 64
Bugzilla::DB::ANON(Bugzilla::DB::MariaDB=HASH(0x557844b5a260), 18) called at Bugzilla/DB.pm line 537
Bugzilla::DB::bz_server_version(Bugzilla::DB::MariaDB=HASH(0x557844b5a260)) called at Bugzilla/DB.pm line 238
Bugzilla::DB::bz_check_server_version(Bugzilla::DB::MariaDB=HASH(0x557844b5a260), HASH(0x55783dcc52b8), 1) called at Bugzilla/DB/MariaDB.pm line 303
Bugzilla::DB::MariaDB::bz_check_server_version(Bugzilla::DB::MariaDB=HASH(0x557844b5a260), HASH(0x55783dcc52b8), 1) called at Bugzilla/DB.pm line 209
Bugzilla::DB::bz_check_requirements(1) called at ./checksetup.pl line 116
at lib/DBIx/Connector.pm line 31.
[root@PR-BugtrackLinux bugzilla]# systemctl status mariadb.service
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3 database server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2024-05-22 13:16:41 PKT; 39min ago
Docs: man:mysqld(8)
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
Process: 1192 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 3232 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mysql-prepare-db-dir mariadb.service (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 3207 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mysql-check-socket (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 1192 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
May 22 13:16:41 PR-BugtrackLinux systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3 database server...
May 22 13:16:41 PR-BugtrackLinux mysql-prepare-db-dir[3232]: Database MariaDB is not initialized, but the directory /var/lib/mysql is not empty, so initialization cannot be done.
May 22 13:16:41 PR-BugtrackLinux mysql-prepare-db-dir[3232]: Make sure the /var/lib/mysql is empty before running mysql-prepare-db-dir.
May 22 13:16:41 PR-BugtrackLinux systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 22 13:16:41 PR-BugtrackLinux systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 22 13:16:41 PR-BugtrackLinux systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3 database server.
done what instruction passed to me from the output
